# Logstash 5.1.1 config file execution error?

Tags: logstash-configuration, elasticsearch-5

This code is used to send slowlog of elasticsearch 5.1.1 to logstash 5.1.1 as an input:

```
    input {
  file {
    path => "C:\Users\571952\Downloads\elasticsearch-5.1.1\elasticsearch-5.1.1\logs\elasticsearch_index_search_slowlog"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

filter {
  grok {  # parses the common bits
    match => [ "message", "[%{URIHOST}:%{ISO8601_SECOND}][%{LOGLEVEL:log_level}]
[%{DATA:es_slowquery_type}]\s*[%{DATA:es_host}]\s*[%{DATA:es_index}]\s*[%{DATA:es_shard}]\s*took[%{DATA:es_duration}],\s*took_millis[%{DATA:es_duration_ms:float}],\s*types[%{DATA:es_types}],\s*stats[%{DATA:es_stats}],\s*search_type[%{DATA:es_search_type}],\s*total_shards[%{DATA:es_total_shards:float}],\s*source[%{GREEDYDATA:es_source}],\s*extra_source[%{GREEDYDATA:es_extra_source}]"]
     }

  mutate {
    gsub => [
      "source_body", "], extra_source[$", ""
    ]
  }
}

output {
  file {
    path => "C:\Users\571952\Desktop\logstash-5.1.1\just_queries"
    codec => "json_lines" 

  }
}
```

When i ran this code it is showing error like this in the command prompt.

```
    [2017-01-04T18:30:32,032][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Pipeline aborted due to error
 {:exception=>#<RegexpError: premature end of char-class: /], extra_source[$/>, :backtrac
e=>["org/jruby/RubyRegexp.java:1424:in `initialize'", "C:/Users/571952/Desktop/logstash-5
.1.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-mutate-3.1.3/lib/logstash/filters/mutat
e.rb:196:in `register'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1653:in `each_slice'", "C:/Users/57195
2/Desktop/logstash-5.1.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-mutate-3.1.3/lib/lo
gstash/filters/mutate.rb:184:in `register'", "C:/Users/571952/Desktop/logstash-5.1.1/logs
tash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:230:in `start_workers'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:161
3:in `each'", "C:/Users/571952/Desktop/logstash-5.1.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline
.rb:230:in `start_workers'", "C:/Users/571952/Desktop/logstash-5.1.1/logstash-core/lib/lo
gstash/pipeline.rb:183:in `run'", "C:/Users/571952/Desktop/logstash-5.1.1/logstash-core/l
ib/logstash/agent.rb:292:in `start_pipeline'"]}
[2017-01-04T18:30:32,141][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash
 API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2017-01-04T18:30:35,036][WARN ][logstash.agent           ] stopping pipeline {:id=>"main
"}
```

Can anyone help me in solving this problem?

This is the code of my slowlog

```
    [2016-12-28T15:53:21,341][DEBUG][index.search.slowlog.query] [vVhZxH7] [sw][0] took[184.7micros], took_millis[0], types[], stats[], search_type[QUERY_THEN_FETCH], total_shards[5], source[{
  "ext" : { }
}],
```

Comment: I posted the code,can you able to help me what  timestamp has to used instead?

Comment: What if you have your [match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok-match) as a hash? I guess you're passing it as an array.

Comment: pls..can you explain in detail because i am new to this environment?

Comment: I changed the timestamp and updated the code and it is showing another error..can you help me in solving this??